# Vert.x how to add type parameter to promise in lambda function

Tags: java, vert.x

I am recently using vert.x framework in java and I am still new to vert.x.

Normally when we initiate future as the following way the `SMObj` automatically assigned to `promise1` promise.

```
Future<SMObj> future = Future.future(promise1 -> {
      ----
});
```

What I want to know is, When I use `vertx.executeBlocking` as following code segment, is there a possible way to set type parameter as `SMObj` to `promise2` (eg: promise2 should be like `Promise<SMObj>`)

```
vertx.executeBlocking(promise2->{
          ----code-----
          promise2.complete(SMObj);
      }, blockRes->{ 
          ----code-----
      }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you just have to use the diamond operator:

```
vertx.<SMObj>executeBlocking(promise2 -> {
   promise2.complete(SMObjInstance);
}, blockRes -> {
   ---- code ---
});
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. Is it possible to use this method with any method that used lambda functions?